# Is it possible to set keydown event delay?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a JavaScript application where the user can push some keys which are sent to the server. It is all working but i can not figure out how to control the speed those events are fired.

The problem is if I push and hold down a key on my keyboard, the first event is rised immediately, then there is a sort of dead time, and finally the event starts to be raised at constant ratio.
I would like to eliminate the initial dead time, to have constant events from the first to the last one.
Is it possible to reach that?
It will be great even to set the time between 2 consecutive fired events.

My code looks like:

```
const keyDownHandler = (e) =>{
    console.log(e.keyCode)
}
document.addEventListener('keydown', keyDownHandler)
```

At the moment, if you open the console, it prints the first one log, then it waits about half a second and then it starts to fire events at constant ratio.
How can i remove the dead time between the first and the second events fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is not specifically related to Javascript. You can experience the same thing whenever you type text in a text editor, if you hold a key down there will be a delay between the first print and the second.

So there is no way to avoid it in the event listener. What you should probably do is to poll the keyboard status every X ms and check whether a key is down.